# How can I plot a function with multiple constants?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have this function

[image]

With 3 constants, R, c, and V. The question I have in hand is to show how the solution curve changes as the parameters change so I need to plot this function with several different value of each constant, other than plotting each function many times is there a way to plot this function just once with a slider to be able vary the constants? I tried looking Plot[Table and Manipulate function but that didn't help me a lot. I also tried looking into the plot function. How can I plot this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way might be to use `Manipulate`

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 sol = q[t] /. 
   First@DSolve[{r q'[t] + q[t]/c == v, q[0] == ic}, q[t], t];
 Grid[{{sol},
   {Plot[sol, {t, 0, maxT}, PlotRange -> {{0, maxT}, {0, maxQ}}, 
     ImagePadding -> 40, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {{"q(t)", None}, {"t", "Solution to the problem"}},
      GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
     PlotStyle -> Red]
    }}],

 {{c, 1.6, "c"}, 0, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{r, .1, "r"}, .1, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{v, 1.5, "c"}, .1, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{ic, 1, "q[0]"}, 0, 2, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{maxT, 1, "time scale"}, 1, 100, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{maxQ, 3, "y scale"}, .1, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny}
 ]
```

Comment: For some reason everytime I use the Manipulate function it gives me the definition of the word Manipulate instead, what am I doing wrong? its on Mathematica web

Comment: @method  it is here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html  I find using google search "Mathematica manipulate"

Comment: here's what I am getting http://i.imgur.com/QFvjBsK.png, I have tried to use a function from the reference link and it seemed to work but I tried to hand write the one you gave me too still getting the definition

Comment: @method I do not use Mathematica online, so I am not sure why it does not work there. so I can't really help on that. I use Wolfram Mathematica desktop (on the PC) not on the cloud one. May be someone else knows why it does not work on Wolfram online.

Comment: I think Mathematica cloud is limited to the functions it can do, if I knew that wouldn't have got it :(, but anyway thank you very much for the answer. That animation is going to help me a lot!

Comment: @method In the image you linked that first orange equal sign is suspicious. It means you are calling [WolframAlpha](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WolframAlphaIntegration.html) and I think you don't need this. I have tried @Nasser `Manipulate` code in online [programing lab](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/) and it works.

Comment: @Pinti thank you it worked